# Scala - how do define a case class dynamically

Tags: scala, case-class

Scala version - 2.11

Ex: case class header(name:String, version:String)

I want to define a configurable case class.

Approach 1: --didn't work

```
val columnList = "name:String,version:String"
case class header(columnList)
```

Approach 2: dynamically create case class on runtime.

How would I go on about doing that? I want to read a list of columns from .config file and be able to represent a case class with the n # of columns.

Any other approaches would be helpful? Thanks.

Comment: How would you even use something that doesn't exist?

Comment: "configurable case class" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: - You can add scala-compiler as a dependency at your project and compile/exec any code at runtime.

Comment: "configurable case class" means there's another file called application.config which includes the schema of the table (column names) and the scala program should read that and create a case class based on the configuration read from the file.

Comment: How are you going to use that case class? What is the purpose of this? I smell [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, in principle you can define a case class at runtime

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val columnList = "name:String,version:String"

val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror
val toolBox = runtimeMirror.mkToolBox()
val classSymbol = toolBox.define(
  toolBox.parse(s"case class header($columnList)").asInstanceOf[ClassDef]
).asClass
```

---

**Update.**

> How can this be used to instantiate an object of `header`?

You can use:

- the toolbox once again

```scala
toolBox.eval(q"""new $classSymbol("aaa", "bbb")""")
```

or

- Scala reflection

```scala
toolBox.mirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
  .reflectConstructor(
    classSymbol.toType.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
  )("aaa", "bbb")
```

or

- Java reflection

```scala
toolBox.mirror.runtimeClass(classSymbol)
  .getConstructor(classOf[String], classOf[String])
  .newInstance("aaa", "bbb")
```

Comment: How can this be used to instanciate an object of header?